# unpacking yaml values in the ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, yaml

i'm a fresher in the professional world as i just joined amid corona situation as being work from i have been involved to understand and write ansible codes and at some level i am growing up by watching through SO posts to get variety of ticks & tricks.

I have the below ansible playbooks..

1- One is `custom_pkgs.yml` which basically installing some custom build packages using `yum` command where it calling a `pkgs.yml` file which lists the packages to be install.

I somewhat understood the code but

```
$ vi custom_pkgs.yml
---
- name: Install License
  hosts: all
  become: yes
  become_user: root
  become_method: sudo
  tasks:
    - name: Include the variables to install the license software
      include_vars:
        file: "vars/pkg.yml"
        name: license

    - name: Install license software
      shell: "yum install -y {{ license[ item ] | join(' ') }}"
      with_items: "{{ license }}"
      changed_when: True
      when: item != "remove"

    - name: Remove any unwanted RPMS
      shell: "yum remove -y {{ license.remove | join(' ') }}"
      changed_when: True
      when: license.remove is defined
...
```

Below is the pkg.yml

```
$ cat pkg.yml
---
license:
 - fenixlmd.noarch
 - tmpwatch
 - xorg-x11-deprecated-libs.i386
 - Tasking.noarch
 - rotate_fix.noarch
 - plexim.noarch
 - interrad.noarch
 - idsd.noarch
 - gsi.noarch
 - java-1.8.0-openjdk
 - java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel
 - java-1.8.0-openjdk-debug
 - flexnet_agent
 - magillem.noarch
 - redhat-lsb-printing
 - redhat-lsb-printing.i686
 - redhat-lsb-core
 - redhat-lsb-core.i686
 - redhat-lsb
 - redhat-lsb.i686
 - git
 - gcc
 - python-devel
...
```

### What i would like to Know:

I am trying to understand about below two lines..

`shell: "yum install -y {{ license[ item ] | join(' ') }}"`  and `when: item != "remove"`

I have went through all the basics of asking question in SO in case i've ask something out of way i would like to be excused as this is my first post.

Regards ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for learning Ansible, this is an old Ansible code. The pkg.yml file defines a list variable called licence containing a list of yum package to install on the remote host using the Ansible **shell** module. `with_items: "{{ license }}"` tell the module to iterate on that variable items.
The When condition help to skip the package when his name is **remove**.
Read the Ansible conditional documentation: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#the-when-statement

But as i told, it's an old code. On Ansible recent version, you will use a yum module to install yum package (create two lists of package: ***package_to_install*** and ***package_to_remove***

```
- name: Install License
  hosts: all
  become: yes
  become_user: root
  become_method: sudo
  tasks:
    - name: Include the variables to install the license software
      include_vars:
        file: "vars/pkg.yml"
        name: license

    - name: Install license software
      yum:
        name: "{{ package_to_install }}"
        changed_when: True
      when: item != "remove"

    - name: Remove any unwanted RPMS
      yum:
        name: "{{ package_to_remove }}"
        state: absent
      changed_when: True
```

Make sure to use a recent Ansible version (2.9).

Read the yum module documentation: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/yum_module.html

You can Also defined only one list of package variable with two fields:

```
  license:
    - { name: fenixlmd.noarch, state: present }
    - { name: tmpwatch, state: absent }
    - { name: xorg-x11-deprecated-libs.i386, state: present }
    .
    .
    .
```

And then use the yum module like that:

```
- name: Install License
  hosts: all
  become: yes
  become_user: root
  become_method: sudo
  tasks:
    - name: Include the variables to install the license software
      include_vars:
        file: "vars/pkg.yml"
        name: license
    - name: Remove any unwanted or install needs package RPMS
      yum:
        name: "{{ item.name }}"
        state: "{{ item.state }}"
      with_items: "{{ licence }}"
```

Comment: idriss, Nice encouraging comment and answer it helps new learners to move forward +1

Comment: Thank you sir for the explanation and sharing the knowledge on the post.

Comment: @safeagile can you solve the issue please ? thank you

Comment: @idrissEliguene, Still i'm bit confused about the usage of `when: item != "remove"` and `when: license.remove is defined` because we just want to install as per the `pkg.yml`, why it has remove condition. Secondly we have already used `include_vars` then i believe we can use `name: "{{ licence}}" `

Comment: @safeagile i thinks the licence variable déclaration it's not good. I thinks they want to declare a variable like: ```license:
 - { name: fenixlmd.noarch, remove: true }
 - { name: tmpwatch, remove: false }
 ``` so they can iterate over "{{ item.name }}"  to the package name, and {{ item.remove }} to the boolean to remove the package or not. And then you can use the conditions:```when: {{ item.remove }}``` to remove the package and ```when: not {{ item.remove }}```to install the package

Comment: How about incorporating/using  the file like `pkg.yml` , can't  we use directly that, likewise `pkg_install.yml` and `pkg_remove.yml` ?

Comment: No you dont need two files for vars definition, just defined two vars on the same files. or you can either defined only one list of variable with fields. read aigain my answer, i add some new spec at the end @safeagile. ANd you dont need two file for each yum install and remove, juste defines two ansible tasks or read my proposition to correctly remove and install package with only one tasks